Firebase Phone Authentication Error: Invalid PlayIntegrity Token and App Verification Issues in Development Mode
I'm developing an Android app that includes phone number sign-in and OTP verification using Firebase. The app is currently in development mode and has not been published on the Google Play Store. However, I'm encountering some issues related to SMS verification and app verification.
E  [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 18002 Invalid PlayIntegrity token; app not Recognized by Play Store.
D  Re-triggering phone verification with Recaptcha flow forced for phone number +91xxxxxxxxxx
I  ForceRecaptchaFlow from phoneAuthOptions = true, ForceRecaptchaFlow from firebaseSettings = false
E  Error while validating application identity: App verification failed - a valid Activity is required to complete the Recaptcha flow
What I've Tried:
Added the SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints of my debug keystore to the Firebase console.
Ensured that the phone number sign-in method is enabled in the Firebase Authentication settings.
Confirmed that the activity initiating the phone number verification is not destroyed or backgrounded during the process.
Questions:
Do I need to have a Google Play Developer account and register my app on the Play Store, even for development and testing purposes, to pass the PlayIntegrity ?
Is there a way to bypass the PlayIntegrity token requirement or Recaptcha flow during development?
Are there any specific configurations needed in the Firebase console or project settings to ensure smooth operation of phone number verification during development?
Any insights or guidance on resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
